# Angularjs - filtering ul from another controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

in my application, I have two controllers, in the first controller, I have a text `input`  and `ul` so that I can filter list with `filter:$rootScope.test`, in the other controller I have only `ul`. What I want to is be able to filter ul from first(`namesCtrl`) and second controler (`x`) in parallel. I am using `$rootScope` as model, it is working on first controller, but  not in the second. Can someone please show how to filter `ul` of first controller and second in same time ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" >
<div ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>

<p><input type="text" id="dSuggest" ng-model="$rootScope.test" ></p>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:$rootScope.test">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
<hr/>
<div ng-controller="x">
<ul>

  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:$rootScope.test">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$('#dSuggest').on("input", function(d){console.log($('#dSuggest').val())});
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
    ];
});
app.controller('x', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    console.log($rootScope);
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
    ];
})
</script>
<p>The list will only consists of names matching the filter.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your input out of the `namesCtrl` controller, like this for instance:

```
...
<div ng-app="myApp" >
<div >
<p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>

<p><input type="text" id="dSuggest" ng-model="$rootScope.test" ></p>

<ul ng-controller="namesCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:$rootScope.test">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>
...
```

Comment: Excuse me this works, but this was just and example actually, I have a projet with the two controllers in different files. How can I adapt this ?

Comment: Having the controllers in separate files should not be a problem...anyway post your code and we'll have a look.